# Sometimes receiving:" Error while performing the callout operation" when using callout mediator in a proxy

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-esb

Sometimes when I am using Callout mediator I am receiving this message specially if I have made  previous calls/callouts before in the sequence.
This is the message I receive: ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error while performing the callout operation.
This specially occurs when using chaining within proxies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="InsChildCustomer"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=", ***********Incoming###########"/>
         <property name="originalMessage"
                   expression="$body"
                   scope="default"
                   type="OM"/>
         <property xmlns:cus="http://www.example.org/customerWSO2/"
                   name="SNIPPMessage"
                   expression="$body/cus:insertChildCustToNSRequest"
                   scope="default"
                   type="OM"/>
         <sequence key="conf:/resources/sequences/InsChildCustomerHeaderSeq.xml"/>

         <filter xmlns:cus="http://www.example.org/customerWSO2/"
                 source="boolean(//cus:insertChildCustToNSRequest/cus:childCustData/cus:customerContacts/cus:customerContact[1]/cus:email)"
                 regex="true">
            <then>
               <property name="customerContacts"
                         expression="//cus:insertChildCustToNSRequest/cus:childCustData/cus:customerContacts"
                         scope="default"
                         type="OM"/>
            </then>
            <else>
               <property name="noContacts" value="1" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <header name="Action" scope="default" value="addList"/>

                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <addressbook xmlns=""
                                     xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                                     xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2015_1.lists.webservices.NS.com"
                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                                     xsi:type="listRel:CustomerAddressbook">
                           <defaultBilling>$1</defaultBilling>
                           <defaultShipping>$2</defaultShipping>
                           <addressbookAddress xsi:type="platformCommon:Address">
                              <addr1>$3</addr1>
                              <addr2>$4</addr2>
                              <addr3>$5</addr3>
                              <customFieldList>
                                 <customField scriptId="custrecord_addr_4"
                                              xsi:type="platformCore:StringCustomFieldRef">
                                    <value>$6</value>
                                 </customField>
                              </customFieldList>
                              <city>$7</city>
                              <state>$8</state>
                              <zip>$9</zip>
                              <country>$10</country>
                           </addressbookAddress>
                        </addressbook>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:billingaddressindicator/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:shippingaddressindicator/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:addr1/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:addr2/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:addr3/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:custrecord_addr_4/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:city/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:state/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:zip/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cus:country/text()"/>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>

                        <send>
                           <endpoint key="conf:/resources/endpoints/NSEndpoint.xml"/>
                        </send>


      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <header xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                 name="platformMsgs:documentInfo"
                 scope="default"
                 action="remove"/>
         <property xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                   xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                   name="isSuccess"
                   expression="//addListResponse/platformMsgs:writeResponseList/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformCore:status/@isSuccess"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <filter xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                 xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                 source="//addListResponse/platformMsgs:writeResponseList/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformCore:status/@isSuccess"
                 regex="true">
            <then>
               <log level="full" separator=", *******before_iterator********"/>
               <property name="customerInternalId"
                         expression="//addListResponse/platformMsgs:writeResponseList/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformMsgs:baseRef/@internalId"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <header name="platformMsgs:platformMsgs:documentInfo"
                       scope="default"
                       action="remove"/>
               <property name="type"
                         expression="//addListResponse/platformMsgs:writeResponseList/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformMsgs:baseRef/@type"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <urn:get xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                              xmlns:urn1="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <urn:baseRef internalId="$1" type="customer" xsi:type="urn1:RecordRef">
                           <urn1:name/>
                        </urn:baseRef>
                     </urn:get>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('customerInternalId')"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <header name="Action" scope="default" value="get"/>
               <sequence key="conf:resources/sequences/customerAddPassport.xml"/>
               <sequence key="conf:resources/sequences/customerAddPreferences.xml"/>
               <callout endpointKey="conf:/resources/endpoints/NSEndpoint.xml">
                  <endpoint name="NSEndpoint">
                     <address uri="https://webservices.sandbox.NS.com/services/NSPort_2015_1"/>
                  </endpoint>
                  <source type="envelope"/>
                  <target xpath="$body/*"/>
               </callout>
               <property xmlns:ns="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                         xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2015_1.lists.webservices.NS.com"
                         name="customerEntityId"
                         expression="//ns:getResponse/ns:readResponse/ns:record/listRel:entityId"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <log level="full" separator=", After_Get"/>
               <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <cus:insertChildCustToNSRequest xmlns:cus="http://www.example.org/customerWSO2/">$1                                                                            
                  <cus:transactionid>$2</cus:transactionid>
                        <InternalID xmlns="">$3</InternalID>
                     </cus:insertChildCustToNSRequest>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg xmlns:cus="http://www.example.org/customerWSO2/"
                          evaluator="xml"
                          expression="$ctx:SNIPPMessage//cus:childCustData"/>
                     <arg xmlns:cus="http://www.example.org/customerWSO2/"
                          evaluator="xml"
                          expression="$ctx:SNIPPMessage//cus:transactionid"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('customerInternalId')"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <header xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                       name="urn:passport"
                       scope="default"
                       action="remove"/>
               <header xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.NS.com"
                       name="urn:preferences"
                       scope="default"
                       action="remove"/>
               <log level="full" separator=", before SNIPP CALL"/>
               <call>
                  <endpoint key="conf:/resources/endpoints/Teacher.QEndpoint.xml"/>
               </call>
               <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="false" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING"
                         value="false"
                         scope="axis2"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <filter source="get-property('noContacts')" regex="1">
                  <then>
                     <log level="full" separator=", *******without_contacts********"/>
                     <enrich>
                        <source type="inline" clone="true">
                           <insertChildCustToNSResponse xmlns="">
                              <Type/>
                              <Status/>
                              <CustomerInternalId/>
                              <CustomerEntityId/>
                              <ContactInternalId>N.A.</ContactInternalId>
                           </insertChildCustToNSResponse>
                        </source>
                        <target type="body"/>
                     </enrich>
                     <enrich>
                        <source type="property" clone="true" property="type"/>
                        <target xpath="//insertChildCustToNSResponse/Type"/>
                     </enrich>
                     <enrich>
                        <source type="property" clone="true" property="isSuccess"/>
                        <target xpath="//insertChildCustToNSResponse/Status"/>
                     </enrich>
                     <enrich>
                        <source type="property" clone="true" property="customerInternalId"/>
                        <target xpath="//insertChildCustToNSResponse/CustomerInternalId"/>
                     </enrich>
                     <enrich>
                        <source type="property" clone="true" property="customerEntityId"/>
                        <target xpath="//insertChildCustToNSResponse/CustomerEntityId"/>
                     </enrich>
                  </then>
                  <else>
                     <log level="full" separator=", *******with_contacts********"/>
                     <drop/>
                  </else>
               </filter>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log level="full" separator=", From false###########"/>
               <property name="errorCode"
                         expression="//addListResponse/platformMsgs:writeResponseList/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformCore:status/platformCore:statusDetail/platformCore:code"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <property name="errorMessage"
                         expression="//addListResponse/platformMsgs:writeResponseList/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformCore:status/platformCore:statusDetail/platformCore:message"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <enrich>
                  <source type="inline" clone="true">
                     <insertChildCustToNSResponse xmlns="">
                        <Status/>
                        <ErrorCode/>
                        <ErrorMessage/>
                     </insertChildCustToNSResponse>
                  </source>
                  <target type="body"/>
               </enrich>
               <enrich>
                  <source type="property" clone="true" property="isSuccess"/>
                  <target xpath="//insertChildCustToNSResponse/Status"/>
               </enrich>
               <enrich>
                  <source type="property" clone="true" property="errorCode"/>
                  <target xpath="//insertChildCustToNSResponse/ErrorCode"/>
               </enrich>
               <enrich>
                  <source type="property" clone="true" property="errorMessage"/>
                  <target xpath="//insertChildCustToNSResponse/ErrorMessage"/>
               </enrich>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/resources/wsdls/Customer.wsdl"/>
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ChildCustomerToSnipp"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="customerInternalId"
                   expression="//InternalID"/>
         <log level="full" separator="**Consumed from IN MQ before Seq**"/>
         <sequence key="ConvertCustomerSoapToJSONSeq"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="**Consumed from OUT Seq**"/>
         <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="snippMemberId"
                   expression="json-eval($.Data)"/>
         <log level="custom" separator="**From Out Seq before Update**">
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                      name="DataProperty"
                      expression="get-property('snippMemberId')"/>
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                      name="customerInternalId"
                      expression="get-property('customerInternalId')"/>
         </log>
         <sequence key="UpdateSnippMemeber"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">Teacher.Q</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Whats your configuration?

Comment: Add the complete error you come across, along with the Synapse configuration.

Comment: This is the complete error.. After that general proxy logs start.
The first proxy sends the message to a queue(along with making other calls as well) and the second proxy listens to the same queue and operates on the received message and sends it to back-end...

Comment: Is there any special configurations required for callout mediators...
Call and callout mediators work mischievously in my esb sometimes one works and some times the other.
In many cases if call is not working using callout does the job and vice-verse .